# Python scripting code to re-check a section

Tags: python

I have a script that pulls some text from a website and I was wondering how to re-check the site if the results are not what I want, then when it returns what I want or max 3 tries, then continue on with the rest of the script?

For Example – Original script;

```
url1 = "xxx.autotrader.com"

data1 = requests.get(url1)

searchKey = 'Toyota'
searchEndKey = '='

textIwant = data1.text[data1.text.find(searchKey)+len(searchKey):data1.text.find(searchEndKey,data1.text.find(searchKey)+len(searchKey)+1)]
```

... Rest of script ...

As you can see, the scrip above extracts a segment of text from the website, so how do I loop back to ‘data1’ if ‘textIwant’ is not what I want?

So Final script would do something like below but I’m not sure of the correct ‘if’ statements;

```
url1 = "xxx.autotrader.com"

data1 = requests.get(url1)

searchKey = 'Toyota'
searchEndKey = '='

textIwant = data1.text[data1.text.find(searchKey)+len(searchKey):data1.text.find(searchEndKey,data1.text.find(searchKey)+len(searchKey)+1)]

textIwant needs to = 12345 
if not, go back to data1 to read the site again
if textIwant now = 12345 then continue with script, if not, return to data1 to try again to max tries = 3
```

... Rest of script ...

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour] and learn to format your questions. That makes it easier for people to read and understand what you want so you can get the help you need quicker.

Comment: Doing this 3 times in a row is not hard but it will run really quickly. Will the site likely change that quickly? Do you need to wait a few seconds between tries?

Comment: The site gets changed every time it reloads (F5) gives changed results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest having a look at the library "retrying", which provides beautiful decorators to do what you want: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/retrying

All you have to do is wrap the code you want to retry in a function, and add a @retry decorator on the function.

Alternatively, you could also just do something like:

```
import requests 
import time

def check_website():
    url1 = "xxx.autotrader.com"
    data1 = requests.get(url1)
    searchKey = 'Toyota'
    searchEndKey = '='

    checked_times = 0
    textIwant = data1.text[data1.text.find(searchKey)+len(searchKey):data1.text.find(searchEndKey,data1.text.find(searchKey)+len(searchKey)+1)]
    checked_times += 1

    while(checked_times < 3 and textIwant != 12345):
        data1 = requests.get(url1)
        textIwant = data1.text[data1.text.find(searchKey)+len(searchKey):data1.text.find(searchEndKey,data1.text.find(searchKey)+len(searchKey)+1)]
        checked_times +=1
        time.sleep(5)

    return (textIwant == 12345)


has_found = check_website()

if(has_found):
    # Do stuff ...
    pass
```

As @coldspeed mentionned, I would advise to wait a bit before every try, because there is close to no chance the website would have updated beween each try otherwise. The code above waits for 5 seconds between each try.

Comment: I think the above modification will do what I want :) Thank you